# Change CSS on an TextField that already contains CSS applied?

Tags: css, apache-flex, textfield

How do I change the CSS rules for a TextField that already has style associated with it ?
This TextField is inside a RichTextEditor.

Here's the code I'm trying:

```
_rSts: StyleSheet = new StyleSheet();
_rSts.parseCSS('font {font-family:Verdana; font-size:12;}');
_rTextField.styleSheet = _rSts;
```

but when I assign the new StyleSheet to the TextField it throws an exception stating that I cannot assign a style to an element already containing a style.
Do you guys know any way around this? Can I remove the default CSS and add mine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the new style individually on the component.  Something like this:

```
_rTextField.setStyle('font-family', 'Verdana');
_rTextField.setStyle('font-size', 12);
```

Howver, the Flash [TextField](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html) is not a Flex component and does not support the Flex approach to styling. The [setStyle](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#setStyle%28%29) method is defined in UIComponent.  The Flex [RichTextEditor](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/RichTextEditor.html#top) does not appear to have a documented TextField child that you can access or customize.  The RichTextEditor also does not define the styles you are trying to set.

So, I'm not convinced you can do what you want to do.

Comment: I was afraid I couldn't do what I want. Thanks for replying.

Comment: The TextField I'm trying to modify is the TextField inside the TextArea which is inside the RichTextEditor. I am able to change the html tags Flex inserts when I type a text just setting the defaultTextFormat of the TextField above. The problem is that the defaultTextFormat I set seems not to be used by Flex when I inject an img tag directly into htmlText property. I though I could override this behavior by forcing a stylesheet on this component. Do you know any way to do what I need?

Comment: I don't have a solution off the top of my head.  But, if you want to hire me I could figure something out.